# Is there a way of listening/proxying a variable in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, proxy, primitive

I'm building a web framework, something like React; one of the things which I would like to improve on React is state.

My idea is something like Svelte, to use state you just create a normal variable (in my case it would be okay to use a function when creating te state, but not when updating it), but how Svelte does this Magic is by compiling, and I would like it to work in vanilla Javascript.

From my understanding this is not exactly possible, but I've still been trying to hack something somehow.

So the part of this state system that is not possible is knowing when a primitive is set and got (setters & getters), I want it to work with scoped variables; so I can't use the `Object.defineProperty` on the `window` or `globalThis`. I've been hacking around for quite some time and here are the only solutions I thought have could worked:

1. Proxing a `new String(string)`, has given weird error of this beeing of the wrong type, unknows values, and stuff.
2. Proxing the `Funtion.arguments` object, but this didn't work.
3. Using `Symbol.toPrimitive`, but I couldn't find a way of using it without a `+` or `${}`.

But as you can see they all have problems, I'm stuck and can't find anything, is there any (even if hacky, though without legacy or deprecated code) way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: This feels like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve by proxying a primitive and/or variable?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this. I think it's better now?

Comment: Did you mean "even if hacky **with** legacy or deprecated code"?

Comment: FWIW, I've expanded my answer to address the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you've described in JavaScript. You can't proxy a primitive, and you can't run code some other way (getter, setter) when a *variable* is read or set, only when a *property* of an object is read or set.

There is an awful thing you can do in loose mode that's disallowed (for good reasons) in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where you have an object with getters and setters that you then put into the environment used for resolving freestanding identifiers using the `with` statement, but again, it's disallowed for good reasons in strict mode (which is the default for modules and other mechanisms that create new contexts, like the body of a `class`).

I hesitate to give an example of it, but for completeness:

```js
// This only works in loose mode, not strict mode
let a = 0;
const obj = {
    get a() {
        console.log(`Getter called, returning a = ${a}`);
        return a;
    },
    set a(value) {
        console.log(`Setter called, setting a = ${value}`);
        a = value;
    }
};
with (obj) {
    console.log(a);
    a = 42;
    console.log(a);
}
```

---

Re your updated question:

> My idea is something like Svelte, to use state you just create a normal variable...but how Svelte does this this Magic is by compiling, and I would like it to work in vanilla Javascript.

I wouldn't try to do it with freestanding variables, have the user provide a state object and convert its data properties to `getter`/`setter` combinations (or replace it with a new version with `getter`/`setter` combinations, etc.):

```js
// Userland code provides a state object
const state = {
    a: 0,
    b: "hi",
};

// Your framework code converts it to using getters/setters
function enhance(obj) {
    const descrs = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
    for (const key of Object.keys(descrs)) {
        const descr = descrs[key];
        if (descr.configurable && "value" in descr && typeof descr.value !== "function") {
            // A simple data property; wrap it in getter/setter
            let value = descr.value;
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                enhance(value);
            } else {
                Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
                    get() {
                        console.log(`Getter called, returning ${key} = ${value}`);
                        return value;
                    },
                    set(newValue) {
                        console.log(`Setter called, setting ${key} = ${newValue}`);
                        value = newValue;
                    },
                    enumerable: descr.enumerable,
                    configurable: true,
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
enhance(state);

// Their code using the properties triggers your getter/setters:
console.log(state.a, state.b);
state.a = 42;
state.b = state.b.toUpperCase();
console.log(state.a, state.b);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a good option (one I'm considering), though I will continue searching for better option.